# Need help understanding a Simple SQL query to retrieve data

Tags: sql

I am having trouble creating a SQL query that will list the names of manager(s) whose employee(s) handle less than two orders.

Here is a picture of the database, I tried to put an output of the database, but had trouble.

http://s22.postimg.org/spou700b5/printout.jpg

Comment: can you put the relevant database info in the question?  I cannot access that image from my current location.

Comment: where is the manager table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT O.Name
  FROM Employee E
  JOIN Employee O ON O.EmployeeID = E.ManagerID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderT T ON T.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
  GROUP BY O.Name
  HAVING COUNT(T.OrderID) < 2
```

Comment: which does O  and T stand for?

Comment: The O is the alias for the second Employee table reference in the query (line 3).  The T is the alias for the OrderT table (line 4).

Comment: i get an error message for the syntax of the FROM clause

Comment: the aliases are kind of throwing off my understanding, anyway you can show me without the aliases?

Comment: Not really, because you are referencing the Employee table twice, so you have to distinguish between the two.  The alias is just a nickname for the table.  The Employee table with employee data has the nickname "E".  So when we say E.ManagerID, we are saying get the ManagerID from the first Employee table in the query.  The OrderT table has the nickname "T".  I used T because we were already using "O" for the Employee table showing Owner data, and you can't use the same alias twice.

Comment: okay, I understand. any idea why i am getting a syntax error in the FROM clause?

Comment: Is this in Microsoft SQL?

Comment: See edited answer for slight adjustment.  Sorry.  I've also included a link to SQL Fiddle for example.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/664d6/10

Comment: i am still getting a FROM error clause :/
 I am using Microsoft access

Comment: Please include Access as a tag in the future.  I don't know Access, but it works in MSSQL, so you should be able to look up in Access help how to implement the same query.